# Bones do not move geometry

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

I have brought an IFC of a crane into blender. The Jib (The arm with the hook at the end) is one group and I am trying to use bones to make it so I am able to lift the jib up and down. 
[image]

I have created a bone through the center of the jib from the base to the end of the Jib. I then click on the jib, and then onto the bone and Ctrl+P. I am unsure which option to choose, but the jib should not deform as it is steel and would not deform in real life. I have therefore tried every single option and none of them allow me to move the jib in the correct way/at all.

after using Ctrl+P the crane moves to the end of the JIB and rotates so it is horizontal. I do not want the crane to move, I want the bone to affect the jib when I move the bone.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If the Jib is an object in its own (different object than the crane) you should select it, then shift select the bone (in pose mode), then press Ctrl P and choose the "bone" option. In 2.8 you will have also to check the "relative parenting" bone option as shown in the picture.

[image]

The bone parenting will transform a whole object accordingly to the bone transformations, whitout deformings, but if the crane is the same object it will be moved too.

If the crane and the jib are in  the same object you have two options:

1) select in edit mode all vertices of the jib, press P and separate the jib from the rfest of the crane, then follow the same procedure.

Or

2) select the whole object, shift select the armature, press Ctrl P and choose "with empty groups". Then select the crane, in edit mode select all vertices of the jib, select the right vertex group in the properties panel and click the weight assign button.

[image]